# What is the perlish way to test a web application, especially with regards to concurrent access?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, web-applications, concurrency, cgi

I am working on a web application that uses CGI.pm to realize the user interaction. Now I like to test my changes by implementing unit tests. These are my requirements:

1. **Perlish** way
2. **Low effort** to implement the Unit test validating a **simple workflow**.
   My web application consists mainly of two forms displaying and changing
   the content of a flat file database.
3. Allow testing the **concurrent** access of multiple user. 
   This should ensure that e.g. the locking is performed the right way. 
   I am not interested in performance measurement.
4. Integration with Ecplise (**EPIC**)
5. Readable and **Speaking** unit tests

So far I have found these packages: [CGI::Test](http://search.cpan.org/~mshiltonj/CGI-Test-0.104/Test.pm), [Test::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~lukec/Test-HTTP-0.16/lib/Test/HTTP.pm), [HTTP::WebTest](http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/HTTP-WebTest-2.04/lib/HTTP/WebTest.pm) and [Test::WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Test-WWW-Mechanize-1.30/Mechanize.pm).

- **CGI::Test** as a project seams rather dead, last change in Oct. 2003.
- **Test::HTTP** focuses on the HTTP connection.
- **HTTP::WebTest** is running tests from test specifications. Many more packages, but last change in Sep. 2003.
- **Test::WWW::Mechanize** comprehensive and modern interface. Maintained for some time by multiple persons. Readable tests, but seams to focus on testing static pages (perhaps this is not correct, but only based on quantity of methods). Filling a form is possible using submit_form_ok, but there is no example showing that it is possible to check the returned page. Testing concurrent access is not obvious for me, too.

So my research would lead to Test::WWW::Mechanize. Will this be a correct way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What are speaking unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to split testing into two parts:

1. Testing interface with Test::WWW::Mechanize. Test::WWW::Mechanize is good for both static and dynamic pages, but it's purpose is dynamic pages. After submit_form_ok you need to use methods like content_contains, content_like and other methods of "CONTENT CHECKING" group. Also, Test::WWW::Mechanize is a WWW::Mechanize subclass, so you can use any WWW::Mechanize methods like "content".

   Testing parallel access. Split that part of your program into separate library and test it using Test::More and fork.

Answer (score 4):

Test::WWW::Mechanize is a good way to go.

Test::WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) and `Test::WWW::Mechanize->new` returns an object that is a subclass of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm).  So it would help you a lot if you read and understand the documentation for those libraries.  For example, the WWW::Mechanize documentation will explain to you how to submit a form and retrieve its content.

## Example

Here is an example that tests simultaneous access by 2 users and shows how to check the results (adapted from the [Catalyst testing tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~mramberg/Catalyst-Runtime-5.7001/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/Testing.pod#ADDING_YOUR_OWN_TEST_SCRIPT)):

```
my $ua1 = Test::WWW::Mechanize->new;  # user agent 1, Bud
my $ua2 = Test::WWW::Mechanize->new;  # user agent 2, Ace

# Log in as each user
$ua1->get_ok("http://localhost/login?username=Bud&password=xxx", "Login 'Bud'");
$ua2->get_ok("http://localhost/login?username=Ace&password=xxx", "Login 'Ace'");

# Go back to the login page and it should show that we are already logged in
$_->get_ok("http://localhost/login", "Return to '/login'") for $ua1, $ua2;
$_->title_is("Login", "Check for login page") for $ua1, $ua2;
$_->content_contains("Please Note: You are already logged in as ",
    "Check we ARE logged in" ) for $ua1, $ua2;
```

## Brief explanation:

**get_ok($url, $msg):**

Checks to make sure $url can be retrieved.  $msg is displayed when the test fails.

**title_is($title, $msg):**

Checks the contents of the <title>...</title> tags.  $msg is displayed when the test fails.

**content_contains($content, $msg):**

Checks if the regular expression $content matches anything in the html body.  $msg is displayed when the test fails.

## More things to think about

You might want to look at [Test::WWW::Mechanize::CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~mramberg/Test-WWW-Mechanize-CGI-0.1/lib/Test/WWW/Mechanize/CGI.pm).  It allows you to test without running a webserver.

The [WWW::Mechanize::FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod) could be useful to you if you are looking for examples.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Especially the links and the example are very helpful. The concurrency I am  interested in it not only allow access for two different users as it is shown in your example, but also an write access while the first one is operated. The later one can only be tested with multiple threads at best from different machine(s). I am sorry that the other answer matches my question better, but I really like and appreciate your super tips for WWW::Mechanize! Thanks, again.

Comment: Fine. But it make me look at your questions and I have found some **very** helpful ones, too.